# CMake: How to choose which include directories get passed for each source file

Tags: c++, command-line, cmake, g++, include-path

I have a project with many source files, and header files. I could add every single directory that contains a header file to CMake's include directories so they are passed via -I option to the compiling of each source file.

```
include_directories(I/will/need/tons/of/these);
```

Is there any way through CMake that I can pass only the relevant include directories to the compiling of each source file?

For example, If i was writing this myself on the command line, I would use a script like this:

```
g++ -I $(./get_include_dirs.sh foo.cpp) -o foo.o foo.cpp
```

where $(./get_include_dirs.sh foo.cpp) is a script that gets expanded to only the include dirs of foo.cpp

Can this be done on CMake? I don't know how to tell cmake to use that script for each file

Comment: You can execute the script from CMAKE and save the output to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you should set include directories not globally but on target level:

```
set(my-target-sources
  source1.cpp
  ...
  sourceN.cpp
)
add_library(my-target
  ${my-target-sources}
)
target_include_directories(my-target
  [PUBLIC|PRIVATE|INTERFACE]
    directory-relevant-to-my-target
)
```

This way, the compiler will look for header files in directory-relevant-to-my-target when compiling my-target. I think that there is no reason for setting the include directories on source file granularity.

For executing a script from CMake you can use execute_process and collect your list of directories in the OUTPUT_VARIABLE parameter but I would not propose that since you will lose inherent portability of CMake when doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SET` call like following;

```
set(HEADERS h1.h h2.h h3.h) 
set(CPP_SOURCE myfunc.cpp)


add_executable(prog ${HEADERS} ${SOURCE_FILES} )
```

PS: It is better to review the file hierarchy, because in general you should use just `include_directories` call.